# How to prevent applications from accessing library's Firebase instance

Tags: android, gradle, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication

I'm working on an Android SDK for a service that uses Firebase as its database. The library includes Firebase as a dependency, like so

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.library'
...
dependencies {
    ....
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:9.4.0'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:9.4.0'
}
```

Now, any application that uses the library can directly perform reads & writes to the service's Firebase database, by using `FirebaseDatabase.getInstance()`, as long as they are authenticated.

But I need modifications to Firebase to occur only through methods exposed by the library. This is necessary to ensure that data in the database is created only a result of certain events.

Is there any way to disallow client apps from accessing the library's Firebase instance, or invalidate such access?

Comment: What do you mean by `as long as they are authorized` ?

Comment: Sorry, I meant authenticated. Corrected it in the question. I'm referring to Firebase's inbuilt authentication here.

Comment: Well in this case it is not enough for "any application" to make request to your database. Remember, you have to place the **google-services.json** file in your project to make requests. Or maybe I misunderstood?

Comment: I have placed the google-services.json file in my library module. However, any app that uses my library can simply access the library's Firebase instance since it can access the Firebase classes packaged with the library.